Remove taskbar in AOSP 13
I am working on AOSP 13.
AOSP code is built for tablet device.
Currently navigation icons are in task bar, is there a straight forward way to permanently remove task bar in AOSP code and navigation icon are still visible same as phone?

In above image task bar is highlighted in red box, navigation icons (back,home,recent apps)are in right side corner of taskbar.

please elaborate more what is "task bar"... and navigation icons, three bottom buttons? way be easier with screenshot in here

@snachmsm I have edited question to put the image of taskbar, please check it

That's default AOSP UI in Android 13 for tablets.
You will need to modify the SystemUI app layouts and related code which places and updates the app icons in the layout, source code at:
[AOSP_ROOT]/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/

and layouts at:
[AOSP_ROOT]/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/layout-land

